# Format decimal that represents hour into HH:mm

Tags: java

I'm trying formatting a Double that represents hour like this:

```
Double totalHours = 1.05;

int hour = totalHours.intValue();
Long minutes = Math.round((totalHours - hour) * 60);

System.out.println(hour + ":" + minutes);
```

In this case I get `"1:3"` but I wold like `"01:03"`. How would I do this?

Or there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00"); // "0" means don't omit leading zero
System.out.println(df.format(hour) + ":" + df.format(minutes));
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minutes)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 String strHourFormat = "HH";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strHourFormat);
 sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strHourFormat);
```